# Bounty giving away more reputation than a user has

Tags: discussion, bounties

I know that 50 points are added by the system when creating a bounty. But I don't understand how the user for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180364/how-do-you-get-file-details-in-a-sharepoint-itemeventreciever-in-the-itemadding-e) can give away 150 points when they have 87 (at time of writing).

How is this possible and what will they end up with if the bounty concludes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rep is taken off of the user when the bounty is added, not when it is awarded.  If you look at their [rep graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90333?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top), you can see they lost 100 rep (50 rep for the bounty is added by the system).